# Need help in Python Pivot table group by

Tags: python, pivot, pandas-groupby

I have the a dataframe something like the below struture :
[image: image1]

I need to make it look it as this :
[image: image2]

Can any one help pls ?

Comment: Please paste the data, or at least, add a description for images

Comment: @ Dorian,Image 1 Details :

Comment: Image 1 : Self understood
Image 2 : 
1. Need to group by Customer, Grp code
2. Print the summary of Grp code for each Customer
3. Like : Total Sum of each Gap code, with individual sum of Ind code
4. Also the Percentage of each Grp code with regards to the total amount of each customer

Comment: @DorianTurba, If any more details, require kindly mention. As i need to close this code at the earliest. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please make sure there is a copy-pastable code which creates the dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the groupby() function with a list and append summarising functions with agg().

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'customer': [1,2,1,3,1,2,3], 
                   "group_code": ['111', '111', '222', '111', '111', '111', '333'],
                  "ind_code": ['A', 'B', 'AA', 'A', 'AAA', 'C', 'BBB'],
                  "amount": [100, 200, 140, 400, 225, 125, 600],
                  "card": ['XXX', 'YYY', 'YYY', 'XXX', 'XXX', 'YYY', 'XXX']})

df_groupby = df.groupby(['customer', 'group_code', 'ind_code']).agg(['count', 'mean'])
```

Comment: I am not sure, as i m bit new to python, i am looking out for the code.

Comment: @Sheriff, you need to have pandas installed on your system and then you can try import like `import pandas as pd` and then try the code provided by @leoburgy

Comment: @leoburgy, it happens :-)

Comment: @leoburgy, Thanks it has solved a part of my job. Actually i wanted the "Percentage of each Group code Amount against the total amount spent by a customer". Say in our case Customer 1 has 2 group codes - 111 and 222. Total amount spent by customer 1 against this 2 group codes is (100+225)+140 = 465.

Comment: so percentage of Group code 111 spent based on Total amount : 69.89 and respectively Group code 222 is 30.11. Now since Group code 111 percentage is more i need to add a new column to dataframe "Category" with value as Group code 111

Comment: Can you kindly help me on this and make my day ?